# Calculating all possible combinations of people in hotel rooms

Tags: php

Given I have the following combination of people wanting to stay in a hotel;

- 3 Adults
- 6 Children

How can I work out all of the different combinations of rooms that could be selected based on the above, where a child cannot be alone in a room and all people must be used? (Note: this is in a PHP application).

For example, the above could be broken down like;

- 1 room with everyone in
- 2 rooms with;

  - 1 adult 6 children
  - 1 adult 0 children
- 2 rooms with;

  - 1 adult 5 children
  - 1 adult 1 child
- etc...

Ideally this should result in a data structure along the lines of;

```
[
    // Room combination
    [
        // Individual Room
        [
            'adults' => 3,
            'children' => 6
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            'adults' => 2,
            'children' => 5
        ],
        [
            'adults' => 1,
            'children' => 0
        ]
    ]
]
```

I have the following code that handles adults however I cannot think how to introduce the concept of children into this.

```
public function partition($left, $last = 1, $ar = [], &$partitions = [])
    {
        if ($left == 0) {
            array_push($partitions, $ar);
        }

        for ($n = $last; $n <= $left; $n++) {
            $b = $ar;
            array_push($b, $n);
            array_merge($partitions, $this->partition($left - $n, $n, $b, $partitions));
        }
        return $partitions;
    }
```

Comment: How may rooms are the in total available?

Comment: max number of rooms is delimited by number of adults, since no children can be alone

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile This just assumes that there could be as many rooms as there are adults in the group (all it is concerned with is calculating every possible combination)

Comment: Ok I wud allow 3 rooms each room with 1 Adult and 2 kids

Comment: That would be an example of a valid combination yes @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: One simple approach without thinking directly about permutation is to focus on adults and those can only be in the combinations of 3 in one room, 3 rooms with 1 adult and 2 rooms with 2 adults in one room and 1 in the other (so only 3 permutations on the adult side). After that just divide the children into the rooms where at least 1 adult is (since it doesn't matter how many adults). That's just my simple logic.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for permutation?

```
function perm($pool,$result=array())
{
  if(empty($pool))
  {
    echo implode(' ',$result).'<br>';
  }else
  {
    foreach($pool as $key => $value)
    {
      $neuerpool    = $pool;
      $neuerresult  = $result;
      $neuerresult[]= $value;
      unset($neuerpool[$key]);
      perm($neuerpool,$neuerresult);
    }
  }
}


perm(array('der hund ','übersprang ','den graben ','mit einem weiten sprung '));
```

Copied from http://phpforum.de/forum/showthread.php?t=210119

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but we worked with scala, I saw his post at the time of developing it, I think we tried to transform his solution by one, and then with some language tools we could transform and combine, I do not know if he can try to reproduce something similar in php, I do not know if it's the most efficient way, but it works pretty fast:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object example extends App {

  case class Room(cant: Int, tipo: String) {
    override def toString: String = " " + cant + "" + tipo
  }

  val tagAdults = " adult(s) "
  val emptyAdult = Room(0, tagAdults)
  val tagChildren = " child(s) "
  val emptyChild = Room(0, tagChildren)

  def perm(x: Room): Seq[List[Room]] = (1 to x.cant).map { i =>
    val result = new ListBuffer[Room]()

    var total = x.cant / i

    while (total > 0) {
      if ((result.map(_.cant).sum + i) <= x.cant) result += Room(i, x.tipo)
      total -= 1
    }

    if (x.cant % i > 0) result += Room(x.cant % i, x.tipo)

    result.toList
  }

  val adults = perm(Room(3, tagAdults))

  val childrens = perm(Room(5, tagChildren))

  val combinators = for {
    x <- adults
    y <- childrens.filter(_.length <= adults.map(_.length).max)
  } yield x zipAll(y, emptyAdult, emptyChild)

  val cleanAdultsBeginZero = combinators.filter(_.forall(_._1.cant > 0))


  cleanAdultsBeginZero.sortBy(_.length).foreach { x =>
    val tag = "room(s)"

    println(s"${x.length} $tag")

    x.groupBy { case (room1, room2) => room1.cant + room2.cant }.foreach { case (key, rooms) =>
      println(rooms.length + " " + tag + " of " + key + " people " + rooms.head)
    }

    println()
  }
}
```

Can you test this code in: 
[jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-scala-online) or
[scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/)

Preview one scala work sheet:

[image]